# Why does this output gain work best?

Tags: control-theory

Suppose I have a discrete time LTI system derived from test data that looks like this:

```
sys = ss([
   1.0000e+00   9.9997e-04;
  -6.6163e-07   9.9983e-01
], [
  -5.1767e-07;
  -1.1265e-04
], [
  -5.0000e-01   1.6724e-03;
  -9.2256e-04  -5.0012e-01
], [
  -9.4466e-07
   3.8677e-05
], 0.001);
```

I know from trial and error results that output feedback gain $K = [3100, 120]$ and feed-forward gain of ~17 is able to stabilize this system almost perfectly. But why? How would I go about deriving these gains mathematically? The gains btw represent a PD controller (P = 3100 and D = 120).

I have tried using dlqr method to generate optimal gains, but this method gives me gains that are far away from the best ones that I have derived using experiments.

```
Qc = C * C';
Rc = eye(size(sys.b)(2)) * 1e-4

[K, f, z] = dlqr(A, B, Qc, Rc)

K = K * inv(C)
```

This results in $K = [99.675, 113.062]$. I suppose the main issue here is that I use C * C' as cost function for state where I should instead use offset weights like [1, 0; 0, 0.001] since tracking performance for x1 is more important than tracking performance for x2 as is evident from manually tweaking the gains. But I don't know this ahead of time. How would I derive the perfect gains knowing only the system model? Is this doable? Is it possible to automate this process and at least eliminate having to tweak Qc and only focus on R?

I also derive output feedback gains by multiplying K with inverse of C since u = -Ky and y = Cx so dlqr returns result that is -KC so therefore if I then multiply it with inverse of C then I get output gains. But why is this never mentioned in literature? Is this even the full picture?

I have also calculated system poles when system is using my experimentally derived output feedback as follows (K = [3100, 120]):

```
[p, z] = pzmap(ss(A - B * K * C, B * K, C, D * K, 0.001))
```

This gives poles $p = [0.99643 + 0.01273i, 0.99643 - 0.01273i]$. This does make sense because there are some minor oscillations in the system when using these gains. (note that this is a discrete system so poles that are <1 mean that the system is stable). It seems that tweaking poles in this case would be an easier approach than tweaking Qc and Rc for dlqr. But what other information can I extract from the values of these poles?

What other information can I extract from this system in general that would help me control it better?

Comment: You might want to ask on https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What has this to do with electronics?

Comment: Perhaps https://dsp.stackexchange.com/ would be a better fit but electronics.stackexchange.com is for electrical engineering, which is definitely related to LTI system theory.

Comment: If you are weighting the output you need `dlqry` however you are using feedforward action which makes the loop much faster if tuned properly. And you have suppressed the input weight a lot so probably your controller is producing huge outputs compared to the LQR one. Hence you are not comparing equal things. Also your performance metric is subjective.

Comment: So how does feedforward action effect the poles/performance of the system mathematically? Also I'm curious about the D matrix. If I plug the D matrix into the output feedback equation of u = KCx + KDu then I get a recursive equation so intuitively the dynamics would be predominantly determined by KCx term. But is this really the case?

Comment: Yes I do need a controller that is much faster than the lqr one. It seems that LQR controller tries to minimize oscillations while I try to tune for minimal overall error and fast convergence which requires high gain and high damping factor.